# Create Frame by Frame Animation in live wallpaper

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation, android-wallpaper

I have an animation with 500 frame. I should create bitmap for each of them to show in live wallpaper's canvas, but it get a lot of performance,
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation-list. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="100" />

......

</animation-list>
```

You can associate this resource to a background view and when you want start the animation.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Will it be seedy enough to be set as background wallpaper and run for 24 hours???

Comment: I think that it is a good way to do this. When you init the animation you should use something like this:    ivGif.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ivGif.getBackground();

                frameAnimation.start();
                frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
            }
        });

Comment: How can I use animation list in live wallpaper in canvas ? I want run it for 24 houres. thanks alot

Comment: really need to use canvas??? If you need to use canvas, i remember that in canvas you can paint a drawable resource. (animation-list is a drawable resource).